# Why Nautilus consumes way too much memory?

Tags: nautilus, python, ram, memory-usage

In the past 4/5 days I noticed something very strange. I am using Ubuntu 13.04 amd64. After some time from the system login I think an hour or two may be, either nautilus or python process uses too much memory about 2.5GB. Normally I kill the process and memory get released, but within another hour or max.

Two repeats the same situation, and this goes forever. Honestly as I have 8GB of memory I do not track always the usage, just when I notice from system load indicator that my computer uses a lot of memory, so I never observed if the memory usage by python or nautilus is incremental (but I think it should be).

Nothing helped to make the problem disappear: reboot, shutdown or even X restart. But what is really strange is that this memory usage is alternating, ex: at first occurrence after system start I always have both processes - 2.5Gb, python - 1.0 GB, after killing them have nautilus - 2.5 GB, after killing it I have python - 2.5GB, and the process repeats. So my question is how to find out the cause of this, how to debug such thing, or at least any suggestions.

Comment: Have you got any nautilus addons/extensions installed?

Comment: I think not, however i do have rabbitvcs installed, it is written in python and is integrated into nautilus scripts folder, but i had never a problem with it.

Comment: Do your system were recently updated? In a terminal type `tail -n50 /var/log/dpkg.log`, edit your post and add the entire output.

Comment: As i recently purged libreoffice and installed openoffice and i switched back to libreoffice there is a lot of trash in that log, therefore i grabbed the last 3000 entries, and surprisingly i got just till 5th of September. I uploaded the output to dropbox [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/frp4tiszy0hy1f9/output.txt)

Comment: I'd check it without rabbitvcs - I think it has to use a fair bit of memory to keep track of SVN objects and that memory gets counted as nautilus'. Just googling "rabbitvcs memory" brings up a lot of things.

Comment: Check out this bug report on launchpad: [Nautilus: memory leak](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/952108) and specifically [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/952108/comments/18) regarding Rabbitcvs.